# a question on Bindable in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

I have a class called which is called ChartInfo,and it has a getter and setter methods as:

```
[Bindable]
public function set isShowingPower(b:Boolean):void
{
   _isShowingPower = b;

   hasChanged();
}

public function get isShowingPower():Boolean
{
   return _isShowingPower;
}
```

The _isShowingPower is the property.

However,if I want to set the _isShowingPower from another class:

```
_chartInfo.isShowingPower(false)
```

It will always give error like:
1195: Attempted access of inaccessible method isShowingPower through a reference with   static type components.charting:ChartInfo.

Could anyone give an idea?Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to access a setter and/or getter you have to do it like a var.

in your case it should be

```
_chartInfo.isShowingPower = false;
```

Answer (score 3):

Setters are used like properties, so `_chartInfo.isShowingPower = false;`